# Manually dispatchEvent DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Is there any way to manually fire the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

I'm trying to write a unit-test for some client-side JavaScript which does some stuff on the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

The following did not work:

```
document.dispatchEvent("DOMContentLoaded")
```

or

```
document.body.dispatchEvent("DOMContentLoaded")
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This works for me in Firefox:

```
var DOMContentLoaded_event = document.createEvent("Event")
DOMContentLoaded_event.initEvent("DOMContentLoaded", true, true)
window.document.dispatchEvent(DOMContentLoaded_event)
```

Answer (score 37):

Since [`initEvent` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent), it's better to use [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) constructor like this:

```
window.document.dispatchEvent(new Event("DOMContentLoaded", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}));
```

Comment: The `cancelable: true` is not necessary since the `DOMContentLoaded` event on either [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) or [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) is not cancelable when it's dispatched by browser, and you may also want to dispatch the [window.onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) that is also not cancelable too.

Comment: and this can't trigger any callback within [`$(function)` from jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) since it will only be invoked one time after the event listener being removed: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.6.1/src/core/ready.js?rgh-link-date=2022-10-29T07%3A31%3A12Z#L62