# DOMContentLoaded event isnt getting fired

Tags: javascript

I execute this code in the head of the document:

```
 console.log('DOMContentLoaded event');
 document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ready, false );
```

However, the function doesnt get called, even after the page is ready?
What is inside the console log does get printed

Notice that i add a javascript file dynamically (it is not hardcoded), and i think it is quite late in the script.. it is after the  window.onload event?
may it be the reason? any way I can trigger the event?

Comment: If you add event listener after the event already happened then yeah, that's a good reason why it won't "work".

Comment: Sounds like what you are really after is manually calling this event? If so, see [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9153314/447356). [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYLcX/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, that's not really a solution. `ready` functions which do not maintain an internal "called" flag would be distracted by that.

Comment: @Bergi true, but looks like that's his best option, no?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'd propose a helper function that knows when the DOM is already loaded and acts appropriate, just like `jQuery.ready` does