# Gravity Forms adding display none

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm creating a custom template inside my WordPress theme, since my template is a completely different layout than my active theme, the template has it's own header & footer and inside of both I have properly declared `wp_head();` and `wp_footer();` respectively.

Inside my template code, I am trying to display a gravity form using do_shortcode, but no form shows. When I inspect the area, I can see the form code, but there is a `style="display:none"` added to the `.gform_wrapper` div.

As one more note, gravity forms is working perfectly throughout the rest of my site (all pages/posts using the active theme), I only have the problem on my custom template.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Although this is an old question it still came up first when I searched for this problem, so I'm adding my solution in case others are searching too. If your theme moves scripts to the footer (frequently recommended for performance reasons) by including one or more of the following lines of code in functions.php:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts'); 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

you'll need to move the Gravity Forms scripts to the footer as well, so they get called after jQuery. You can do this by adding the following code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter('gform_init_scripts_footer', 'init_scripts');
function init_scripts() {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The add_filter part is all I needed - thanks for that @Linn :)

Comment: The add_filter bit fixed this for me also

Comment: A note for anyone who gets here and doesn't want to read all the many solutions here. For me, the issue was trying to call the form via the `gravity_form()` function call, and placing that below `wp_footer()`.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you have conditional logic being used on your form. Anytime conditional logic is present the entire form is set to display: none; and then javascript is used to only show the fields that should be shown.

HOWEVER this requires Gravity Forms being able to output the necessary Javascript using the WordPress built in enqueue function... which outputs the Javascript in your footer.

Your theme probably does not have this function call in your theme's footer.php file:

```
<? php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This function call, which all themes should have (but many people forget to include), enables plugins to output code in the footer of a theme dynamically. If it isn't present, the theme can't output the necessary code.

This is most likely why your form is not displaying properly.

Answer from: http://www.gravityhelp.com/question/why-is-there-a-style-attribute-of-displaynone-being-added-my-form-isnt-showing-up/

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help, the wp_footer is in the theme footer and there are no conditional logic fields.

Comment: This gave me the clue I needed to look into other Javascript errors on the page. Getting rid of the errors made the forms show up again.

Comment: Same problem here. Has nothing to do with wp_footer() for me. I'm also forced to a CSS hack.

Comment: Great Tip! @SarahLewis nailed it.

Comment: For those who can't reach to provided link anymore (because they moved), [here's a link to webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150312035432/http://www.gravityhelp.com/question/why-is-there-a-style-attribute-of-displaynone-being-added-my-form-isnt-showing-up/)

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this to work.

For conditional logic to work, the jQuery that comes with WordPress must be deregistered, 1.8.3 must be loaded in the header and gravityforms.min.js, conditional_logic.min.js and jquery.maskedinput.min.js must be loaded in the footer:

```
<?php
 function modify_jquery_version() {
 if (!is_admin()) {
     wp_deregister_script('jquery');
     wp_register_script('jquery',
     'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js', false, '1.8.3');
     wp_register_script('migrate',
     'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js', false, '1.4.1');

     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
     wp_enqueue_script('migrate');
     }
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'modify_jquery_version');

 function footer_load() {
 if (!is_admin()) {
wp_enqueue_script('gravity','/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/gravityforms.min.js','','',true);
wp_enqueue_script('conditional','/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/conditional_logic.min.js','','',true);
wp_enqueue_script('masked','/wpcontent/plugins/gravityforms/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js','','',true);
    }
}

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'footer_load');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

My WP theme was calling an older version of jQuery (hosted by Google) and that was causing the display:none property to be applied to my Gravity Forms. I updated the enqueue script to the latest version of jQuery and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, the actual solution is to add 
   `gravity_form_enqueue_scripts($form_id)`
to your header.php file.

From the Gravity forms support doc itself: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/embedding-a-form/#enqueue-scripts-and-styles

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will help but maybe try this:

```
.gform_wrapper{
   display:block !important;
}
```

I know for a fact that inline styles override any stylesheets but `!important` helped me with overriding some plugins styles.

Try also searching for the `style="display:none"` in the plugin files. Use Textwrangler or another editor where you can search multiple files. This also helps me a lot for editing the themes and plugins.

Comment: yeah! its working is it a right solution? or any other way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue just deactivating a plugins called Autoptimize that optimizes websites concatenating the CSS and JavaScript code, and compressing it.

Pretty obvious once you found it.

Comment: Would have been better to troubleshoot as per [AO's FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/faq/) really, deactivating is such an ... extreme measure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just now.

Two problems: This old theme was using jQuery 1.5.1 and all the plugins it had bundled were written for older jQuery. The conditional logic in Gravity Forms was not working because of old jQuery version AND because I had renamed a conditional logic field.

After removing/fixing up some of the incorrect condition logic drop downs, and upgrading jQuery version on the site, things started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by any other script on the page throwing an error. Check the console to make sure there are no broken scripts

Answer (score 0):

For me, the cause was a console error in FireFox related to:

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(ev){
     console.log(event, ev);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a **temporary fix**, I added this to `<theme_dir>/footer.php`, just before `</body></html>`:

```html
<script>
jQuery('.gform_wrapper').show();
</script>
```

This will tell jQuery to show all divs with the `.gform_wrapper` class.

I already tried moving `wp_footer();` around and all other suggestions from here. and from other sites. Nothing worked. I also tried disabling cache, purging cache, removing plugins, etc. No JS errors. No forms being shown.

One thing I noticed is the problem only shows up when two conditions are met:

1. User is not logged-in.
2. The form uses conditional logic.

If any of the two are not there, the form loads fine.

I'll add more info here once I find out why this is happening.

## Edit:

The main issue is that [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) is not being fired. It will happen if not all http requests finish (like pending css, js, images, etc.). The following code (borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724894/1582649) forces the event and shows the form.

```
window.document.dispatchEvent(new Event("DOMContentLoaded", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}));
```

I still don't know why this is happening, since there are no pending requests showing in console. Everything seems to be loading properly. I tried to copy the entire site to another server and it works there. This leads me to think it's something related with the host provider. Maybe some kind of cache.

For now, I'll leave that piece of code at the end of `<theme>/footer.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was very simple: I just deactivated the *Enable jQuery Migrate Helper* plugin. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case deactivating the Plugin "Gravity Forms - Save & Continue Auto Load" solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing `style="display:none"` from the `.gform_wrapper` div? Or changing it to 
`style="display:block"`

Comment: There is no place for me to remove it. Also, it is only being added to the custom template page. The same form, same shortcode on other pages / posts work fine "no display:none style"

Comment: You may need to look in the plugin files and search for gform_wrapper or all display. It's there some where just a matter of finding it.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I thought the reason was:
I put the Gravity shortcode into a  (and maybe it detected and inserted the "display: none" to it`s iframe?)

```
<div id="layer_2" style="display: none">
[gravityform id=123 title=false ajax=true]
</div>
```

The frame code:

```
<iframe style='display:none;width:0px;height:0px;' src='about:blank' name='gform_ajax_frame_16' id='gform_ajax_frame_16'></iframe>
```

Since I removed "display: none" from the div, the Gfrom worked fine. Than added a script to the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("#_layer_2").attr("style", "display: none"); });
```

But! The Gform works fine with "iframe style=display: none" even without the JS code above. **The real reason was:** a lack of one "

```
</div>
```

" in the page code.

Answer (score -2):

Is "display:none" set for the .gform_wrapper class itself? Then just change it in the css file of Gravity Forms.

However, the wrapper might have an ID or another class for which the display:none could be set.

Last but not least, there could be a broken jQuery animation for the wrapper, which might be why it stays hidden.

Comment: If you change the gravity forms css your changes will be overwritten as soon as the plugin is updated. You should add the changes to your theme's css using more specific css selectors.

Comment: <div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper" id="gform_wrapper_4" style="display:none"> - this is autommatically being added to the form when using the shortcode. There is no place for me to remove it. Also, it is only being added to the custom template page. The same form, same shortcode on other pages / posts work fine "no display:none style"