# Advanced Custom Fields breaks Gravity Forms form with Conditional Logic

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, advanced-custom-fields

When I create a gravity form without conditional logic it works perfectly, but when I add conditional logic it doesn't show up at all.
There are no errors either, and I have wp-debug set true..
It does appear when I disable the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, so I know it's a conflict between those two plugins.

Comment: Can you supply the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: I don't know where the error in the code is, probably in a plugin file. I just call the form with a shortcode.<br>I tested it with multiple themes, but that didn't help, so it's definitely in a plugin

Answer (score 1):

**Possible causes**

**Cause 1: Javascript function error**  :
In Gravity forms, If your form uses conditional logic that means it has an inline style of display:none applied, **if your page has any JavaScript issues they can prevent the Gravity Forms scripts from running**, and when those scripts can't run the inline display:none style can't be removed.

**Cause 2: Duplicate jQuery library**   :
Also it might be possible that, The theme is including it's own copy of jQuery after WordPress has already included its copy in the page header.
If that is the case then remove another copy of jQuery ( From Theme ).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure jQuery is loaded in the header and gravityforms.min.js is deferred to the footer - works for me at least.
See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43949673/7994214