# Trigger a built in event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I noticed that you can make and trigger your own customs events and event listeners in Javascript [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/773263). Can I do something similar to trigger a pre-existing event artificially?

For example say I'm loading external Javascript and I want to artificially trigger `DOMContentLoaded` after the event has actually fired.

Comment: @mplungjan the method I linked uses an event object which is created. Since I'm not creating an event, I'm using a pre-existing one, I'm not sure how to access that pre-existing event object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153314/manually-dispatchevent-domcontentloaded . So yes. The question just becomes, why would you ever use that over other solutions, since it has a risk of breaking 3rd party code in the project.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Code goes here
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded triggered');
});
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
// Define that the event
event.initEvent('DOMContentLoaded', true, true);
// target can be any Element or other EventTarget.
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

### A more modern approach

The ["old-fashioned way"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#The_old-fashioned_way) for creating events (as seen above) has been deprecated. It is now better to use the `Event` constructor instead, as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).

```js
// Code goes here
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded triggered');
});

const event = new Event('DOMContentLoaded', {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});
const cancelled = !document.dispatchEvent(event);
if (cancelled) {
  // A handler called preventDefault.
  console.log('The event was cancelled...');
} else {
  // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
  console.log('The event was not cancelled...');
}
```